# Did 500 scientists sign a declaration saying "There Is No Climate Emergency"?

Tags: climate-change

In this [press release from The Global Warming Policy Foundation (GWPF)](https://www.thegwpf.com/european-climate-declaration-there-is-no-climate-emergency/), there is a claim that 500 prominent climate scientists and professionals has submitted a declaration that there is no “**climate emergency**”.

> As the latest U.N. climate summit begins in New York, a new,
>   high-level global network of 500 prominent climate scientists and
>   professionals has submitted a declaration that there is no “climate
>   emergency”.

I see the official letter but I don't see any signatures of scientists. Who has the list of scientists and does the list even exist?

Comment: This sounds very like the "500 'scientists'" who say that the Earth is only 6000 years old.

Comment: @DJClayworth, really? That's interesting. Where can I read about it?

Comment: it's interesting how they phrase it, "climate scientists and professionals" implies that there are 500 people who study the climate and aren't alarmed.  However, "climate scientists AND professionals" allows them to link the one or two actual climate scientists that claim that with the much larger list of economists, programmers, doctors, engineers, authors, etc

Comment: @DenisS but neither of those two phrasing are from the declaration itself, which says "more than 500 knowledgeable and experienced scientists and professionals in climate and related fields".  The OP claim is not from the group organizing the declaration, https://clintel.nl/prominent-scientists-warn-un-secretary-general-guterres/

Comment: @DavePhD it's in the article linked by the user, which people are more likely to read than the actual paper itself.  The paper in your answer states "500 scientists and professionals" but the article states "500 prominent climate scientists and professionals".  The article linked by OP adds the word "climate" to the phrasing where it wasn't there in the paper.

Comment: @DenisS I understand.  This is the actual group that organized the declaration https://clintel.nl/prominent-scientists-warn-un-secretary-general-guterres/ They just say "500 prominent scientists and professionals" on their site, without the word "climate".

Comment: @DavePhD right, I saw that from your answer (already upvoted as well :)) but the article takes some very creative liberties with phrasing to make the headline much more sensational.  "2 climate scientists and 498 professionals disagree with climate change" is more boring than "500 climate scientists and professionals disagree with climate change"

Comment: @DenisS Actually, I take back some of what I said, because I found this: https://clintel.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/ecd-press-briefing.pdf directly on the clintel website.

Comment: @DavePhD there we go, they lifted it directly from the Clintel people.  Doesn't make it any more correct as a statement, but now the fault for the misleading headline falls directly on the Clintel group.

Comment: What I've read about the GWPF suggests that it's a highly dubious organisation, with a mysterious source of funding (They've rejected FOI requests regarding their funding and have shifted their lobbying into a non-charity Global Warming Policy Forum to avoid the scrutiny that charities re supposed to be subject to).  Have they provided an actual list of actual names with actual contact details so the list can actually be verified?

Comment: If 1% of 1% of all humans can be considered a "scientist", that's 700k. How notable would it be that 0.0007% of "scientists" signed a declaration?

Comment: @Acccumulation 500 is 0.07% of 700k, not 0.0007%.  Still a small fraction though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The list of 500 is available in [this document](https://www.technocracy.news/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/ED-brochureversieNWA4-1.pdf).

The list is grouped by country and starts with:

> SCIENTISTS AND PROFESSIONALS FROM BELGIUM
>
> 1. Rob Lemeire, Publicist on Environmental and Climate Issues, ECD Ambassador
> 2. Eric Blondeel, retired Civil Engineer.
> 3. Emiel van Broekhoven, Emeritus Professor of Economics, University of Antwerp
> 4. Christophe de Brouwer, MD, Honorary Professor of Environmental and Industrial
>      Toxicology, Former President of the School of Public Health at the Université Libre de
>      Bruxelles
> 5. Christian Dierick, Lead Expert, Energy Technology Solutions
> 6. Ferdinand Engelbeen, Former chemical process automation engineer, Akzo Nobel
>      Chemicals
> 7. Samuel Furfari, Professor of Energy Geopolitics at the Free University of Brussels
> 8. Georges Geuskens, Emertitus Professor of Chemistry, Free University of Brussels and
>      Expert Publicist on Climate Science
> 9. Drieu Godefridi, PhD in Law, author of several books
> 10. Jan Jacobs, Science Journalist Specializing in Climate and Energy Transition
> 11. Raymond Koch, Retired Research director at Lab. Plasma Physics, RMA Brussels and
>       Fellow Lecturer at UMons.
> 12. Henri A. Masson, Emeritus Professor Dynamic System Analysis and Data Mining,
>       University of Antwerp
> 13. Ferdinand Meeus, Retired Research Scientist, IPCC expert Reviewer AR6
> 14. Jean Meeus, Retired Meteorologist, Brussels Airport, Author of the Best Seller
>       Astronomical Algorithms
> 15. Ernest Mund, Honorary Research Director, FNRS, Nuclear Engineering
> 16. Bart Ooghe, Geologist & Geophysicist, Independent Scientist
> 17. Jozef Verhulst, Author
> 18. Jean van Vliet, Retired Specialist in Space Weather
> 19. Appo van der Wiel, Senior Development Engineer

The most are from Italy: 113.

The [letter](https://clintel.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/ecd-letter-to-un.pdf) uses the phrasing "more than 500 knowledgeable and experienced scientists and professionals in climate and related fields".  Not all are "scientists" as per the title that the OP wrote.  As seen above, one person is simply listed as being an "author" and another is listed as "PhD in Law, author of several books".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100402/discussion-on-answer-by-davephd-did-500-scientists-sign-a-declaration-saying-th).

Comment: And has anybody checked that these are real people? Could some/many/all of them be just made up names and titles? It's easy to find 500 nutjobs to sign anything, even easier to make them up.

Comment: As I was curious I started to go through the CVs of the so called 500 scientists and stopped after about 5 or six. One, perhaps even the so called embassador of UK has Duke as the most relevant title. Another published papers on children and maths, another one basically was an engineer confining earthslides. A chemist deal with computation of hydrogenoid systems.... And so forth.

Answer (score 11):

Yes the letter has been signed by 500 people but very few of them are actual climate scientists or in related fields (environmental science, ecology, etc).

Many of them have links to oil companies and/or climate denying groups.

Many of the claims in the letter are wrong and have been debunked.

Here is what actual scientists think about the letter and the claims it makes: https://climatefeedback.org/evaluation/letter-signed-by-500-scientists-relies-on-inaccurate-claims-about-climate-science/

Comment: You may want to add some quotes from the link you provided for posterity sake and to back your points up about the 500 people who signed.  There are some good quotes in that link that would effectively back your answer up much better.  Otherwise this is a good answer.